# Timecut: Recording Scrolling HTML/JS Fails

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

The following HTML/javascript, when opened on Chrome, Chromium, Firefox, or Safari, produces a nicely flowing white on black set of text that we want to use to display the end credits at the end of our live stream.  We want to record this and create an mp4 file with the results.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>End Credits Example</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <style>
            body {
                background-color: black;
                color: white;
                font-size: x-large;
                font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
                    margin: auto;               
            }
            h1 {
                text-align: center;
                margin-top: 120px;
            }
            p {
                width: 70%;
                margin: auto;
                padding: 10px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <h1>Headline 1</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <h1>Headline 2</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <h1>Headline 3</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <h1>Headline 4</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <h1>Headline 5</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <h1>Headline 6</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <div style="height: 800px;"></div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function pageScroll() {
                window.scrollBy(0,1);
                scrolldelay = setTimeout(pageScroll,10);
            }
            
            window.onload=pageScroll();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I had planned to use [timecut](https://github.com/tungs/timecut) to produce the mp4, however the following command line results in a video with nothing but a black screen:

```
timecut end-credits.html --viewport="1280,720" --fps=30 --duration=10 --frame-cache --pix-fmt=yuv420p --output=video.mp4
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you tried extending the `duration`? The text takes quite a bit to scroll into the viewport in your example, which makes me wonder if the 10 "virtual seconds" they cite in their documentation is a bit too quick for your animation to actually make anything of substance appear.

Comment: I just removed the blank <div> at the top.  The text comes in almost immediately now.  I've also experimented with durations as long as 60 seconds and it produces the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research, I've determined that the issue was the javascript method for the animation.  Replacing requestAnimationFrame which was subtly mentioned in tungs' blog post regarding timecut.  The following code works perfectly with timecut now:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>End Credits Example</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <style>
            body {
                background-color: black;
                color: white;
                font-size: x-large;
                font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
                    margin: auto;               
            }
            h1 {
                text-align: center;
                margin-top: 120px;
            }
            p {
                width: 70%;
                margin: auto;
                padding: 10px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <h1>Headline 1</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <h1>Headline 2</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <h1>Headline 3</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <h1>Headline 4</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <h1>Headline 5</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <h1>Headline 6</h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <div style="height: 800px;"></div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            const element = document.getElementById('wrapper');
            let start, previousTimeStamp;
            let done = false

            function step(timestamp) {
              if (start === undefined) {
                start = timestamp;
                }
              const elapsed = timestamp - start;

              if (previousTimeStamp !== timestamp) {
                // Math.min() is used here to make sure the element stops at exactly 8000px
                const count = Math.min(-0.1 * elapsed, 8000);
                element.style.transform = 'translateY(' + count + 'px)';
                if (count === 8000) done = true;
              }

              if (elapsed < 60000) { // Stop the animation after 60 seconds
                previousTimeStamp = timestamp
                !done && window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
              }
            }

            window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
            
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```